# FileNotFoundException for drawable in drawable-xhdpi-v4

Tags: android, drawable, filenotfoundexception

We got a crash log from Google Play and it seems some drawable in  drawable-xhdpi-v4 is not found. However, we didn't have a drawable-xhdpi-v4 folder and do have edit_bg.9.png in res/drawable-xhdpi/. I found this post after searching, but it seems not helpful and no accepted answers there.

Thanks for any advice.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/edit_bg.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200bb
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2172)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3589)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:642)
at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:56)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/edit_bg.9.png
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:421)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2163)
... 34 more
```

Comment: try keeping edit_bg.9.png in drawable folder

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Thanks! I guess all 9 patch files should be put in drawable folder since they are stretchable?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right

Comment: What is the reason this issue will come ?